"message":"execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow"
    constructor(
    address[] memory setupAddys,
    uint256 _totalTokensForSale,
    uint256 _softCap,
    uint256[] memory _Participation,
    uint256[] memory _Times,
    uint256 _lpPercentage,
    uint256 _liquidityLockPeriod,
    bool _burn
) public {
    require(setupAddys[0] != address(0), "Address zero validation");
    require(setupAddys[1] != address(0), "Address zero validation");
    require(_lpPercentage >= 5100 && _lpPercentage <= 10000, "Min 51%, Max 100%");
    require(
        _Participation[0] < _Participation[1],
        "Max participation should be greater than min participation"
    );
    UniswapV2Router02  = IUniswapV2Router02(setupAddys[0]);
    admin = IAdmin(setupAddys[1]);
    // tokenAddress = address(setupAddys[2]);
    // creator = address(setupAddys[3]);
    // totalTokensForSale = _totalTokensForSale;
    // softCap = _softCap;
    minParticipation = _Participation[0];
    maxParticipation = _Participation[1];
    // startTime = _Times[0];
    // endTime = _Times[1];
    lpPercentage = _lpPercentage;
    liquidityLockPeriod = _liquidityLockPeriod;
    factory = msg.sender;
    burn = _burn;
    isInitialized = true;
    setSaleParams(
        setupAddys[2],
        setupAddys[3],
        _totalTokensForSale,
        _softCap,
        _Times[0],
        _Times[1]
    );
}

/// @notice  Admin function to set sale parameters
function setSaleParams(
    address _token,
    address _saleOwner,
    uint256 _totalTokensForSale,
    uint256 _softCap,
    uint256 _saleStart,
    uint256 _saleEnd
) private {
    require(!sale.isCreated, "Sale already created.");
    require(
        _token != address(0),
        "setSaleParams: Token address can not be 0."
    );
    require(_saleOwner != address(0), "Invalid sale owner address.");
    require(
        _totalTokensForSale!= 0 &&
            // _hardCap != 0 &&
            _softCap != 0 &&
            _saleEnd > block.timestamp,
        "Invalid input."
    );
    require(
        _saleEnd <= block.timestamp + 8640000,
        "Max sale duration is 100 days"
    );
    require(
        _saleStart >= block.timestamp,
        "Sale start should be in the future"
    );
    require(_saleStart < _saleEnd, "Sale start should be before sale end");

    decimals = IERC20Metadata(_token).decimals();

    // Set params
    sale.isCreated = true;
    sale.token = IERC20(_token);
    sale.saleOwner = _saleOwner;
    sale.totalTokensForSale = _totalTokensForSale;
    sale.saleEnd = _saleEnd;
    sale.softCap = _softCap;
    saleStartTime = _saleStart;


    // Emit event
    emit SaleCreated(
        sale.saleOwner,
        sale.totalTokensForSale,
        sale.saleEnd,
        sale.softCap
    );
}


function getliquidityToken() public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 liquidityToken = (totalTokensForSale * lpPercentage) / 10000;
    return liquidityToken;
}

function totalTokenSale() public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 totalToken = (totalTokensForSale * lpPercentage) / 10000;
    uint256 tokenTotal = totalToken / 10**18;
    return tokenTotal;
}

function lpPercent() public view returns (uint256) {
   uint256 totalToken = (totalTokensForSale * lpPercentage) / 10000;
   uint256 tokenTotal = (totalToken) / 10**18;
   return tokenTotal;
}

function getliquidityEth() public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 liquidityEth = (sale.totalBNBRaised * lpPercentage) / 10000;
    return liquidityEth;
}

function changeSaleOwner(address _saleOwner) external onlySaleOwner {
    require(block.timestamp < saleStartTime, "Sale already started");
    require(_saleOwner != sale.saleOwner, "Already set to this value");
    require(_saleOwner != address(0), "Address 0 validation");
    sale.saleOwner = _saleOwner;
    emit LogChangeSaleOwner(_saleOwner);
}


// Participate function for manual participation
function participate() external payable {
    require(
        msg.value >= minParticipation,
        "Amount should be greater than minParticipation"
    );
    require(
        msg.value <= maxParticipation,
        "Amount should be not greater than maxParticipation"
    );
    _participate(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

// Function to participate in the sales
function _participate(
    address user,
    uint256 amountBNB
) private {
    require(block.timestamp >= startTime, "Sale hasn't started yet");
    require(block.timestamp <= sale.saleEnd, "Sale has finished");

    if (isWlEnabled) {
        require(isWl[user], "Only for whitelisted users");
    }

    Participation storage p = userToParticipation[user];

    if (isParticipated[user]) {
        require(p.amountBNBPaid + amountBNB <= maxParticipation, "Exceeds max participation");
    }

    // Calculate amount of tokens buying
    uint256 amountOfTokensBuying = 0;
    if (sale.totalBNBRaised > 0) {
        amountOfTokensBuying = (amountBNB * sale.totalTokensForSale) / sale.totalBNBRaised;
    } else {
        // Handle case when sale.totalBNBRaised is 0
        amountOfTokensBuying = (amountBNB * sale.totalTokensForSale); // Assign full token amount
    }

    require(amountOfTokensBuying > 0, "Can't buy 0 tokens");

    // Update sale statistics
    sale.totalTokensSold += amountOfTokensBuying;
    sale.totalBNBRaised += amountBNB;

    // Update user participation details
    p.amountBNBPaid += amountBNB;
    p.amountBought += amountOfTokensBuying;

    userToParticipation[user] = p;

    // Mark user as participated if not already marked
    if (!isParticipated[user]) {
        isParticipated[user] = true;
        numberOfParticipants++;
    }

    // Emit event
    emit TokensSold(user, amountOfTokensBuying);
}


// Expose function where user can withdraw sale tokens.
function withdraw() external {
    // require(block.timestamp > sale.saleEnd, "Sale is running");
    require(
        saleFinished == true && isSaleSuccessful == true,
        "Sale was cancelled"
    );
    require(isParticipated[msg.sender], "User is not a participant.");

    // Retrieve participation from storage
    Participation storage p = userToParticipation[msg.sender];

    require(p.areTokensWithdrawn == false, "Already withdrawn");

    uint256 amountWithdrawing = p.amountBought;

    p.areTokensWithdrawn = true;

    if (amountWithdrawing > 0) {
        // Transfer tokens to user
        sale.token.transfer(msg.sender, amountWithdrawing);
        // Trigger an event
        emit TokensWithdrawn(msg.sender, amountWithdrawing);
    }
}

function setWLEnabled(bool _enabled) external onlySaleOwner {
    require(isWlEnabled != _enabled, "Already set to this value");
    isWlEnabled = _enabled;
    emit LogSetWLEnabled(_enabled);
}

function setMultiplyAddressesWL(address[] memory users, bool _isWL) external onlySaleOwner {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        setAddressWL(users[i], _isWL);
    }
}

function setAddressWL(address user, bool _isWL)  private {
    require(isWl[user] != _isWL, "Already set to this value");
    isWl[user] = _isWL;
    emit LogSetAddressWL(_isWL);
}


function finishSale() external onlySaleOwnerOrAdmin {
    require(sale.totalBNBRaised >= sale.softCap, "SoftCap not reached");
    require(saleFinished == false, "The function can be called only once");
    if (sale.totalBNBRaised >= sale.softCap) {
        uint256 BNBForLiquidity = (sale.totalBNBRaised * lpPercentage) / 10000;
        uint256 tokensForLiquidity = (sale.totalTokensForSale * lpPercentage) /10000;
        BNBAmountForLiquidity = (BNBForLiquidity) / 10**18;
        tokensAmountForLiquidity = (tokensForLiquidity) / 10**18;

        require(sale.token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= tokensAmountForLiquidity, "Insufficient token balance for liquidity");

        sale.token.approve(address(UniswapV2Router02), tokensAmountForLiquidity);

        isSaleSuccessful = true;
        saleFinished = true;

        (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) = UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidityETH{value: BNBAmountForLiquidity}(
            address(sale.token),
            tokensAmountForLiquidity,
            tokensAmountForLiquidity,
            BNBAmountForLiquidity,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp + 3600
        );
        emit LogLiquidityInfo(amountToken, amountETH, liquidity);
        if(burn){
          burnTokens();
        }else{
            refundTokens();
        }
    } else {
        saleFinished = true;
        withdrawLeftoverIfSaleCancelled();
    }
    emit LogFinishSale(isSaleSuccessful);
}

I'm getting this error when trying to add liquidity to fairlaunch smart contract.
this the result of sale.totalBNBRaised and sale.totalTokenForSale
    totalBNBRaised: "2000000000000000"
    totalTokensForSale: "1000000000000000000000"
    lpPercentage: "70"

then the error come from this
uint256 BNBForLiquidity = (sale.totalBNBRaised * lpPercentage) / 10000;
uint256 tokensForLiquidity = (sale.totalTokensForSale * lpPercentage) /10000;

with execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow"
Please help.

I try to create function to see the result for
BNBAmountForLiquidity = sale.totalBNBRaised.mul(lpPercentage).div(10000);
tokensAmountForLiquidity = sale.totalTokensForSale.mul(lpPercentage).div(10000);

Function :
function lpPercent() public view returns (uint256) {
   uint256 amountForLiquidity = sale.totalTokensForSale.mul(lpPercentage).div(10000);
   return amountForLiquidity;
}

function getliquidityEth() public view returns (uint256) {
   uint256 nativeAmountForLiquidity = sale.totalBNBRaised.mul(lpPercentage).div(10000);
   return nativeAmountForLiquidity;
}

and the result is
getliquidityEth: 1200000000000000 (0.0012 ETH)
lpPercent: 6000000000000000000000 (6000 tokens)

then i change the finishsale function to get some required
function finishSale() external onlySaleOwnerOrAdmin {
            require(sale.totalBNBRaised >= sale.softCap, "SoftCap not reached");
            require(!saleFinished, "The function can be called only once");

            if (sale.totalBNBRaised >= sale.softCap) {
                // Calculate BNB and tokens for liquidity using SafeMath
                BNBAmountForLiquidity = sale.totalBNBRaised.mul(lpPercentage).div(10000);
                tokensAmountForLiquidity = sale.totalTokensForSale.mul(lpPercentage).div(10000);

                require(BNBAmountForLiquidity > 0, "BNBAmountForLiquidity is zero");
                require(tokensAmountForLiquidity > 0, "tokensAmountForLiquidity is zero");

                uint256 currentTokenBalance = sale.token.balanceOf(address(this));
                require(currentTokenBalance >= tokensAmountForLiquidity,
                        string(abi.encodePacked("Insufficient token balance for liquidity: have ",
                        uint2str(currentTokenBalance), " need ", uint2str(tokensAmountForLiquidity))));

                sale.token.approve(address(UniswapV2Router02), tokensAmountForLiquidity);

                isSaleSuccessful = true;
                saleFinished = true;

                try UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidityETH{value: BNBAmountForLiquidity}(
                    address(sale.token),
                    tokensAmountForLiquidity,
                    tokensAmountForLiquidity,
                    BNBAmountForLiquidity,
                    address(this),
                    block.timestamp.add(3600)
                ) returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) {
                    emit LogLiquidityInfo(amountToken, amountETH, liquidity);
                } catch Error(string memory reason) {
                    // This is executed in case revert() was called inside UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidityETH
                    revert(reason);
                } catch (bytes memory lowLevelData) {
                    // This is executed in case of a failing assertion, division by zero, etc.
                    revert(string(lowLevelData));
                }

                if (burn) {
                    burnTokens();
                } else {
                    refundTokens();
                }
            } else {
                saleFinished = true;
                withdrawLeftoverIfSaleCancelled();
            }
            emit LogFinishSale(isSaleSuccessful);
        }

        function uint2str(uint256 _i) internal pure returns (string memory) {
               if (_i == 0) {
                   return "0";
               }
               uint256 j = _i;
               uint256 length;
               while (j != 0) {
                   length++;
                   j /= 10;
               }
               bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
               uint256 k = length;
               while (_i != 0) {
                   k = k-1;
                   uint8 temp = (48 + uint8(_i - _i / 10 * 10));
                   bytes1 b1 = bytes1(temp);
                   bstr[k] = b1;
                   _i /= 10;
               }
               return string(bstr);
           } 

then the result still same
Transaction failed: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xcc361f580590D40edfE809C7Aba736e0B798a63E","to":"0xBff27065f6D43809327D8ebec6Ea349734a3D67f","data":"0x8f86f5ea","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow","data":"0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011","cause":null}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at checkError (json-rpc-provider.ts:78:1)
    at Web3Provider.<anonymous> (json-rpc-provider.ts:642:1)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (json-rpc-provider.ts:1:1)


With only this piece of code and without more details it's hard to say.
What function did you call? with what arguments ?
An overflow or underflow happens when a calculation result is either less or more than the maximum or minimum of the type used.
Here is a more detailed explanation
Since it seems you are only using uint256 size numbers it means that a calculation in your code ends up being more than type(uint256).max or less than type(uint256).min and it throws an error.
You need to find this and resolve it.

The error is from this

The error from this line (wrong calculation)
BNBAmountForLiquidity = (sale.totalBNBRaised * lpPercentage) / 10000;
tokensAmountForLiquidity = (sale.totalTokensForSale * lpPercentage) /10000;
let say the amount of sale.totalBNBRaised is 0.01 ETH and sale.totalTokensForSale is 1000 tokens
then i get the error reason="execution reverted: arithmetic underflow or overflow"

Maybe can i dm you in telegram? i need help for this.
